# How to get the name of the parent_id of a category table from post table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have the following table in "Category" table.

| id | name | parent_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | student | NULL |
| 2 | teacher | NULL |
| 3 | math_student | 1 |
| 4 | science_student | 1 |

I have the following table in "Post" table.

| id | name | category_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ajay | 3 |
| 2 | Mohan | 3 |

Post.php file from Models

```
  public function category(){
            return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id', 'id');
  }
```

if I place the below code I am getting the name of 3rd id that is math_student.

```
$post->category->name
```

but I want to get the name of the parent_id of the category i.e. - "**student**"

I have tried the following code but it is wrong.

```
$post->category->parent_id->name
```

please suggest me the solution

Comment: how is the relation that uses `parent_id` defined? (something like your `category()` thingy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up a relationship using `parent_id` to find the model instance of `Category` within itself.

In the Category.php model:

```php
public function parent(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

After that, you will be able to:

```php
$post->category->parent->name;
```

Answer (score 1):

Within the Category Model, add parent relationship:

```
 public function parent(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'parent_id', 'id')->withDefault();
    }
```

Then, you can get the parent name

```
$post->category->parent->name
```